# Asp.net Mvc 2 DisplayFor Performance Issue?

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-2

In my recent project which is using Asp.net Mvc 2, we found that the DisplayFor has performance issue. I'm not so sure whether it is the **real** issue or did I miss something?

I hope some Asp.net Mvc Guru can explain it to me. :)

Model.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var cust = new Customer()
            {
                CustomerId = i + 1,
                Name = "Name - " + (i + 1),
                Address = "Somewhere in the Earth...",
                EmailAddress = "customerABC"
            };

            yield return cust;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult V1()
    {            
        return View(Customer.GetCustomers());
    }

    public ActionResult V2()
    {
        return View(Customer.GetCustomers());
    }
```

V1 (which has performance issue)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Customer>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    V1
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>V1</h2>
    <table>
    <%foreach (var cust in this.Model)
      {%>
        <%= Html.DisplayFor(m => cust) %>  
      <%} %>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

And Template is

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Customer>" %>
<tr>
    <td><%= this.Model.CustomerId %></td>
    <td><%= this.Model.Name %></td>
    <td><%= this.Model.Address %></td>
    <td><%= this.Model.EmailAddress %></td>    
</tr>
```

V2 (no performance issue)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Customer>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    V2
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>V2</h2>
    <table>
    <%foreach (var cust in this.Model)
      {%>
        <tr>
            <td><%= cust.CustomerId%></td>
            <td><%= cust.Name%></td>
            <td><%= cust.Address%></td>
            <td><%= cust.EmailAddress%></td>    
        </tr>
      <%} %>
      </table>
</asp:Content>
```

I can easy see the performance difference between V1 and V2.

**EDIT**: When I deploy to my local IIS 7 (with Release version) and it (V1) becomes very fast. The issue is solved, but I still want to know the reason. :)

Thanks,
Soe Moe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Caching is enabled only in release mode.  If you run the application in debug mode, you might see a performance hit due to disk accesses.

See also:
http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/22/how-to-improve-htmlhelper.renderpartial-performances-donrsquot-run-in-debug-mode.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I switched debug to false and the performance went back to what I expected it to...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that DisplayFor() uses a lambda expression which is compiled and executed at runtime.

Therefore, the performance difference in V1 can be attributed to this "intermediate" compilation step.

V2 is simply a property access which does not need any compilation.

I'm taking a guess here, but I imagine that IIS7 is smart enough to keep a cached copy of the view (and the compiled lambda expressions) around for future re-use, meaning subsequent render times will be comparable to V1 in IIS 6.

Comment: The assumption that IIS7 is the key factor here, is not correct. See Levi's answer for the correct information.

Comment: IIS7 was mentioned after the answer was accepted so I cannot delete it :(