# Slow performance with MVC2 DisplayFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm iterating through a collection on my view model. The collection contains HealthLifeDentalRates which implement IBeginsEnds. I have a Display Template BeginsEnds that displays the date range. This results in very slow performance. If I simply the date range (see commented code), it's fine. I think how I'm defining the lambda is the problem but not sure how to change it.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Data.OrderBy(x=>x.HealthLifeDentalRateCode))
{ %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.FiscalPeriodString()) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.HealthLifeDentalRateCode) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Rate) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.IsDental.YesNo()) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.DisplayFor(i => item, "BeginsEnds") %>
            <!-- <%= Html.Encode(item.Begins.ToDateString()) %> - <%= Html.Encode(item.Ends.ToDateString()) %> -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", item.Loaded)) %>  - <%= Html.Encode(item.LoadedBy) %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>
```

Comment: It appears to be something to do with resolving the display template. I've even tried to give it the path the to the template with no improvement.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709103/asp-net-mvc-2-displayfor-performance-issue

Comment: I had looked at that (after I posted) but changing to Release doesn't improve anything.

Comment: Is your DisplayTemplate in /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates? That's the first searched path, so it'll be resolved fastest if it's in that folder.

Comment: It was. Thanks Jon. The real answer was that I changed the Toolbar to Release but didn't change the web.config. Once I did that, everything was fine. Many thanks to Brad Wilson for correcting my brain fart.